# Having to hit enter to finish a script. How can I change that?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sh.getName() !== 'Daily' || e.range.columnStart !== 18 || e.value !== 'Checked')return;
    e.source.getSheetByName('History').appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 6, 15).getValues()[0])
    sh.deleteRows(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

I have this script and it works great the problem is I have to type checked per row and hit enter. I compile and verify the rows all week and then "check" them On Sunday. So I may have 200 or more needing the "checked" trigger at once. It would be great to be able to copy and paste the word "Checked" down the whole column. BUT the script only works when I hit enter per line. Is there a way to change that? I want to just having the word "checked" pasted in the column and it will trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use onEdit.

instead add a menu item that will process the entire sheet looping on each row, or that works based on the selected range.

it will run faster and easier to use.